# MySQL searching "äåö" in a UTF-8 table doesnt find anything

Tags: mysql, encoding

The data is displayed correctly but when doing searches it doesn't find anything. This is how data is stored in a table with UTF8 encoding.

```
Default charset: utf8mb4
names: utf8
character_set_client : utf8
```

[image]

```
SELECT * FROM article WHERE description like '%några%' //returns null but it should return one row
SELECT * FROM article WHERE description like '%nå%' //works
SELECT * FROM article WHERE description like '%någ%' //returns null
```

I think mysql converts å to a.

I have tried to convert the search query to utf8 using php function utf8_encode($str). But no success here.
How can I solve this issue?

Comment: Have you tried checking other functions as well e.g. instr(description,'%några%' ) > 0

Comment: Tried it now. NO success.However it works if I search for %nÃ¥gra%

Comment: possible duplicate of [UTF-8 all the way through](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/279170/utf-8-all-the-way-through)

Comment: "nÃ¥gra" stored in the database and "några" are obviously not the same words. You have an encoding problem when inserting into the database, storing your data as garbage.

Comment: So the screenshot I posted is not in utf8?

Comment: @Error404 It is UTF8 misinterpreted as something else, probably Latin1.

Comment: "några" encoded in UTF-8 will display as "några" when interpreted as UTF-8. "några" encoded in Latin-1 will display as "några" when interpreted as Latin1. A string misinterpreted or misconverted at some point will look like garbage.

Comment: @deceze copy your last comment and post it as an answer. I truncated all tables and set the connection to utf8. The new data is readable in the database. and therefore the search result works as expected. Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> "nÃ¥gra" stored in the database and "några" are obviously not the same words. You have an encoding problem when inserting into the database, storing your data as garbage. – deceze [15 mins ago](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21277361/mysql-searching-aao-in-a-utf-8-table-doesnt-find-anything/21277866#comment32060965_21277361)
>
> "några" encoded in UTF-8 will display as "några" when interpreted as UTF-8. "några" encoded in Latin-1 will display as "några" when interpreted as Latin1. A string misinterpreted or misconverted at some point will look like garbage. – deceze [2 mins ago](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21277361/mysql-searching-aao-in-a-utf-8-table-doesnt-find-anything/21277866#comment32061382_21277361)
>
> duplicate of [UTF-8 all the way through](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/279170/utf-8-all-the-way-through) – deceze 16 mins ago